# Is there any easy way to change the permissions for the reboot command in MX Linux?

Tags: linux, reboot

I acquired a new desktop a couple of months ago, and, feeling adventurous, I thought I would take a chance on a different Linux distribution from Ubuntu, which I'd used exclusively up to that point, and installed **MX Linux**. On the whole, I quite like MX Linux; I don't regret installing it. However, one oddity of the distribution has recently been causing me grief.

I realised shortly after installing MX Linux that **calling `reboot` on its own will not do anything**. You have to call **`sudo reboot`**. Initially, this was just a minor irritation. However, I'm now trying to do some more exciting stuff with **scripting**: a context in which having to get superuser privileges every five minutes would be a serious pain in the neck. **Is there any easy way of changing things so that one could call `reboot` on its own?** Is there some other command, which doesn't require superuser privileges, and which would also restart the system?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind typing in a password (a good practice) you create $HOME/bin/reboot that contains the line:

`sudo /sbin/reboot`

Make sure your PATH has $HOME/bin at its beginning.

If you want to call reboot without typing a password, add this line to the end of /etc/sudoers

`YourUserID ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot  # Replace YourUserID with your user id.`

This gives your user the right to call /sbin/reboot without typing a password. You'll need to logout and log back in for this to take effect.